# Pass a function as an argument for another function in Julia

Tags: julia

As mentioned in the title, I want to pass a function as an argument for another function in Julia. However, I want the passed function to be partially specified, such as:

```
func1(a, b) = println(a, b)

func2(a, func::Function) = func(a)

func2(1, func1(b=0)) # returns an error
```

An alternative is to build a new function func3 such as

```
func3(a) = func1(a, b=0)
func2(1, func3)
```

But it does not look so elegant. Is it possible not to define a new function?

Comment: Still, the last sentence isn't clear to me.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `func2(1, a->func1(a, 0))`?

Comment: Should `b` always equal `0`? Please make it easy. We are not here to play a guessing game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with this: I do not honestly know what you're trying to do, but I am just going to look at your source code from just pure Julia.

Your source code contains some runtime and logic errors. So instead of figuring out the "how-to" on your request, let's look at the errors first.

**Line 1:**

```
julia> func1(a, b) = println(a, b)
func1 (generic function with 1 method)
```

This function on it own has no error. So let's move on. Please note that it returns `nothing` which is of type `Nothing`.

**Line 2:**

```
func2(a, func::Function) = func(a)
func2 (generic function with 1 method)
```

This function on its own has no **"runtime error"**, but there is a **"logic error"** here with the statement `func(a)` because of how you called `func2` as we will see later.

**Line 3:**

```
func2(1, func1(b=0))
```

This is where the **"runtime"** and **"logic"** error really piles up. So let's look at this line statement closely.

- `func1(b=0)` will throw an error on its own because you're using a keyword argument for a positional argument. I guess you're coming from Python where this won't error:

```py
>>> def add(a):
        return a * 1

>>> add(a=1)
1
```

However, in Julia it does:

```
julia> function add(a)
           return a * 1
       end
add (generic function with 1 method)

julia> add(a=1)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching add(; a=1)
Closest candidates are:
  add(::Any) at REPL[1]:1 got unsupported keyword argument "a"
```

Take a look at the [section of Julia documentation about functions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/) to learn more about how Julia functions work.

- `func2(1, func1(b=0))`: Now let's assume we've fixed this statement and now used:

```
func2(1, func1(0));
```

however there is still two errors here.

1. The **runtime error** is we've not passed the `a` argument to `func1` which is actually what your question is about: "how do I partially specify `func1`".
2. And the **logic error** is you explicitly passed `a` as `1` to `func1`, so it demands you passing it explicitly to `func1` as well. To pass it implicitly there are two ways: go into some sophistication methods (which I won't even bother going into), or use a global variable (which will slow your performance, but is good for this case-study).

So now let's assume we have a variable `a = 1` now. At this point our new source code now looks like this:

```
a = 1;

func1(a, b) = println(a, b);

func2(a, func::Function) = func(a);

func2(a, func3(0))
```

Well Julia has `Base.Fix1` and `Base.Fix2` for partially specifying a two-argument function. We'll use `Base.Fix1` (since we're concerned with `a` which is the first argument):

```
func3 = Base.Fix1(func1, a);
```

We now have a third function which is fixed to the variable `a`. So as long as we only pass `a` implicitly to `func2(a, func3(0))`, both `func2` and `func3` will both use the global variable `a`. Now lets run the code:

```
julia> a = 1;

julia> func1(a, b) = println(a, b);

julia> func2(a, func::Function) = func(a);

julia> func3 = Base.Fix1(func1, a);

julia> func2(a, func3(0))
10
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching func2(::Int64, ::Nothing)
Closest candidates are:
  func2(::Any, ::Function) at REPL[3]:1
```

- As seen above the `func3(0)` actually runs correctly printing `a` and `b` (which is `1` and `0`). However, there is still an error (which I guess you might have figured out now). You're using the returned value of `func3` and not the function itself. Your type annotation was `func2(a, func::Function)`, so you have to change the design. I would stop here since I can't make any recommendations as I do not know what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You should get the error because `func1(a, b)` gets two positional arguments, meanwhile, you're passing just the first one to it! So the result is `func1` won't work and throws an error!
I didn't understand you here:

> Obviously, I can't specify `b` by just passing a value to `b` in the `func1`. How should I do that?

Because it's not *obvious* actually(!), since you specified `b=0`.
You can do this:

```
julia> func1(a, b) = println(a, b)
func1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> func2(a, b, func::Function) = func(a, b)
func2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> func2(1, 0, func1)
10
```

---

## An alternative way

Another way is to use the [Varargs functions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Varargs-Functions):

```
julia> func1(a...) = println(a)
func1 (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> func2(a, func::Function) = func(a...)
func2 (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> func2([1, 0], func1)
10
```